# Where can i find ThirdPartyCall webservice WSDL file?

Tags: php, avaya

Can anyone tell me where can i find ThirdPartyCall webservice WSDL file ? i am trying to develop click to call functionality for AVAYA phone through my custom application.

Do i need any authentication to access that wsdl file ? if so please tell me the process

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear where you are trying to find the web service.

If you have an AES (Application Enablement Services) then you can use the Telephony Web Service to make a call through web service call.

WSDL location:
http://aes-address:8080/axis/services/TelephonyService?wsdl

Or if you want to use https then the port is 8443.

You can read documentation for AES 6.3:
http://downloads.avaya.com/css/P8/documents/100171777

You must use HTTP Basic Authentication (detailed in the documenation).